# Referencing JComboBox values that are added dynamically

Tags: java, dynamic, combobox, reference

I'm new to Java (having switched over from -gulp- VisualBasic), and so far I've been getting along just fine with all the examples provided on this site. One thing I can't figure out is how to reference combo boxes and labels that are added dynamically (or assign listeners to them). Here's my problem set:

I am writing a program to import items from excel and output them into a KML file for Google Earth. Since I am not requiring the user to populate a pre-specified Excel format, I need to account for variations in the location of different fields within Excel. I have figured out how to add the combo boxes via an iterator, but what has stopped me is how to use them to reference a label later (since they are all created with the name 'comboBox' and 'label').

I have an example of my Excel file, as well as my GUI, but I unfortunately I don't have enough rep to post a picture. To describe it, the user imports an Excel file (with a title bar that says what the column contains: ID, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, LOCATION), and the iterator creates an equal number of combo boxes to have the user choose which of their columns matches up with the three set options for Google Earth (Label, Description, Location). What I need each combo box to do is reference it’s corresponding label ('Label' = 'ID') so when I run the export feature, the appropriate cell data is populated in the KML file.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the response by Scott Corbett, I figured out how to solve this and am just now getting around to posting the answer. I cut out a lot of the parameters and variables since they are irrelevant, while still trying to provide an example that worked for me.

```
//object to contain the filter
public class FilterSelection {
    private JLabel importOption;
    private JComboBox importSelection;

    public FilterSelection (JLabel importOption, JComboBox importSelection){
        this.importOption = importOption;
        this.importSelection = importSelection;
    }

    public JComboBox getImportSelection() {
        return this.importSelection;
    }
}

//builds a filter to determine what each column in Excel the cells represent
public class ImportFilter extends JDialog {
    private TreeMap<Integer, String> headerList = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
    private ArrayList<FilterSelection> filterList = new ArrayList<FilterSelection>();

    public ImportFilter(...) {
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        buildFilterSelection(...));
        addFilter(headerList);
    }

    public void buildFilterSelection(...) {
        //builds a TreeMap from data in Excel cells
        for(Iterator<Cell> cit = row.cellIterator(); cit.hasNext();) {
            headerList.put(cell.getColumnIndex(), cell.getStringCellValue().trim());
        }
    }

    public void addFilter(TreeMap<Integer, String> headerList) {
        JPanel importFilter = new JPanel();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(importFilter);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //iterates through the TreeMap to create a JComboBoxe and JLabel for each Excel cell with data in the header row
        Set set = headerList.entrySet();
        Iterator headerIterator = set.iterator();
        while (headerIterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry headerMap = (Map.Entry)headerIterator.next();
            String header = (String) headerMap.getValue();

            final JComboBox comboBox;
            JLabel label = new JLabel(header);
            comboBox = new JComboBox(new String[] {"", "Location", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Label", "Description"});

            //uses JLabel text to determine what object to select in the JComboBox
            switch (label.getText().toUpperCase()) {
            case "LOCATION":
                if (locationFilter == false) {
                    comboBox.setSelectedIndex(1);
                    locationFilter = true;
                }
                break;
            case "NAME":
                if (labelFilter == false) {
                    comboBox.setSelectedIndex(4);
                    labelFilter = true;
                    }
                break;
            }

            //adds JComboBox and JLable to ArrayList
            FilterSelection filter = new FilterSelection(label, comboBox);
            filterList.add(filter);
            comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
                    //do something here when the JComboBox is changed
                }
            });

            //adds JComboBox and JLabel to the JPanel
            importFilter.add(label);
            importFilter.add(comboBox);
        }
    }
}

//runs through an entire Excel sheet and references the filter to determine how the cells are formatted based on their column
public class PointsBuilder {
    public void PointsBuilder (ArrayList<FilterList> filterList) {
        for(Iterator<Cell> cit = row.cellIterator(); cit.hasNext();) {
            Cell cell = cit.next();
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            try {
                //checks the filter for the corresponding column of the cell being read
                switch (filterList.get(cell.getColumnIndex()).getImportSelection().getSelectedIndex()) {
                    case 0:
                        //the column of this cell had no values in the filter
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        //the column of this cell contains a location
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        //the column of this cell contains a label
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        //the column of this cell contains a description
                        break;
                }
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                //this block catches any data that is in columns beyond where the filter ended based on the header info (ex: last header column = 5; current cell column = 7)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you dynamically add an object, add it to an arraylist as well.  That will preserve a reference for you and you can iterate through the arraylist whenever you need to find it.